# Solve the recurrence relation $f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 3)$

Tags: complex-numbers, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

This is a problem I was playing with that troubled me greatly.

$f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 3)$

$f(1) = f(2) = 1$

$f(3) = 2$

So, the goal is to try and find a solution for f(n).

I tried using the regular method that is given in [Johnsonbaugh](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131593188) , which involves finding a solution to an alternative recurrence relation, given by:

$S_{n} = t^{n}$

$S_{n} = S_{n - 1} + S_{n - 2} + S_{n-3}$

$t^{n} = t^{n - 1} + t^{n - 2} + t^{n - 3}$

$t^{n} - t^{n - 1} - t^{n - 2} - t^{n - 3} = 0$

$t^{3} - t^{2} - t - 1 = 0$

Now, you're supposed to find the roots of the above auxiliary equation, but you need all of the roots, and [two of them are complex](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E3+-+t%5E2+-+t+-+1+%3D+0)

$t = 1.8393$,

and also:

$t = -0.41964 + 0.60629i$

and its conjugate

$t = -0.41964 - 0.60629i$

Therefore,

$S_{n} = a(1.8393)^{n} + b(-0.41964 + 0.60629i)^{n} + c(-0.41964 - 0.60629i)^{n}$

Now, it is a matter of solving the set of linear equations for $a$, $b$, $c$ given by the initial conditions.

$S_{1} = 1 = a(1.8393) + b(-0.41964 + 0.60629i) + c(-0.41964 - 0.60629i)$
$S_{2} = 1 = a(1.8393)^{2} + b(-0.41964 + 0.60629i)^{2} + c(-0.41964 - 0.60629i)^{2}$
$S_{3} = 2 = a(1.8393)^{3} + b(-0.41964 + 0.60629i)^{3} + c(-0.41964 - 0.60629i)^{3}$

Now, this is supposed to yield a solution for f(n), if I didn't mess anything up, where

$f(n) = a(1.8393)^{n} + b(-0.41964 + 0.60629i)^{n} + c(-0.41964 - 0.60629i)^{n}$

Now, how do I solve this, and is it right?

Comment: you can try to solve the recurrence applying the Z-transform.

Comment: Yeah that's right. When you solve for $a,b,c$ you will see that $b$ and $c$ will be equal and the imaginary parts will the cancel out for all $n$.

Comment: This is the [Tribonacci number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html), there is a lot literature around for you to check against your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally fine to have complex roots, because they will come in conjugate pairs, so when you raise each to the same power and add, the imaginary parts will cancel. I didn't check all your math in great detail but your overall approach looks fine. The only minor thing I would suggest is that if you want your answer to be totally correct, you should write down the roots in closed form instead of with decimal approximations. As for how to solve for $a,b,c$, you have the equations and so you just need to solve a $3 \times 3$ linear system of equations. If you don't know how to solve a linear system, you can look it up online, it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

In matrix form, we can construct a matrix $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ such that

$\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(n+1) \\
f(n) \\
f(n-1)
\end{array} \right)
= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(n) \\
f(n-1) \\
f(n-2)
\end{array} \right)
= A
\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(n) \\
f(n-1) \\
f(n-2)
\end{array} \right)$

Generalizing, we shall have,

$\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(n+k) \\
f(n+k-1) \\
f(n+k-2)
\end{array} \right)
= A^k
\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(n) \\
f(n-1) \\
f(n-2)
\end{array} \right)$

Let's put $k=n−3$ and $n=3$, then we shall have

$\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(n) \\
f(n-1) \\
f(n-2)
\end{array} \right)
= A^{n-3}
\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(3) \\
f(2) \\
f(1)
\end{array} \right)$

With spectral decomposition of $A=V\Lambda V^{-1}$, where we have

$\Lambda=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1.8392868 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -0.4196434+0.6062907i & 0  \\
0 & 0 & -0.4196434-0.6062907i
\end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1.8392868 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & (0.7373527)e^{(2.176234)i} & 0  \\
0 & 0 & (0.7373527)e^{-(2.176234)i}
\end{array} \right)$

and

$V = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-0.8503402 & -0.1411941-0.3752032i & -0.1411941+0.3752032i \\
-0.4623206 & -0.3094252+0.4470501i & -0.3094252-0.4470501i \\
-0.2513586 & 0.7373527 & 0.7373527
\end{array} \right)$

so that

$\Lambda^n=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1.8392868^n & 0 & 0 \\
0 & (0.7373527)e^{(2.176234)ni} & 0  \\
0 & 0 & (0.7373527)e^{-(2.176234)ni}
\end{array} \right)$

Hence, we have

$\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(n) \\
f(n-1) \\
f(n-2)
\end{array} \right)
= V\Lambda^{n-3}V^{-1}
\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(3) \\
f(2) \\
f(1)
\end{array} \right)
= V\Lambda^{n-3}V^{-1}
\left( \begin{array}{c}
2 \\
1 \\
1
\end{array} \right)$

For example, for $n=20$, we have,

$\left( \begin{array}{c}
f(20) \\
f(19) \\
f(18)
\end{array} \right)
= V\Lambda^{17}V^{-1}
\left( \begin{array}{c}
2 \\
1 \\
1
\end{array} \right)
=\left( \begin{array}{c}
66012 \\
35890 \\
19513
\end{array} \right)$